# C++ Optional Implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, template, library, optional

I haven't done much programming in C++, so I figured I'd try making an `Optional` class. I'm mainly concerned that I didn't follow good conventions or that I didn't use exceptions well. I know that there are no comments, but for now, let's ignore that.

The idea is that my `Optional` class can be used instead of pointers and `nullptr` when I need to return an optional value.

**optional.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace extra { // I'm putting random library classes/functions in this namespace
    template <typename T>
    class Optional
    {
    public:
        const static Optional<T> empty;
        static Optional<T> of(const T &v);
        static Optional<T> of(T *v);
        T get() const;
        bool hasValue() const;
        ~Optional() { if (value != nullptr) delete value; }
    private:
        Optional(T *v) : value{ v } {}
        const T *value;
    };

    template<typename T>
    const Optional<T> Optional<T>::empty = Optional::of(nullptr);

#include "optional.impl"
}
```

**optional.impl**

```
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
Optional<T> Optional<T>::of(const T &t) {
    return Optional<T>{ new T(t) };
}

template<typename T>
Optional<T> Optional<T>::of(T *t) {
    if (t != nullptr) return Optional<T>{ new T(*t) };
    return Optional<T>{ nullptr };
}

template<typename T>
bool Optional<T>::hasValue() const {
    return value != nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
T Optional<T>::get() const {
    if (!hasValue()) throw std::runtime_error("Tried to get the value from an optional that has no value");
    return *value;
}

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const Optional<T>& t1, const Optional<T>& t2) {
    if (!t1.hasValue() && !t2.hasValue()) return true;
    else if (!t1.hasValue() || !t2.hasValue()) return false;
    return t1.get() == t2.get();
}

template<typename T>
bool operator!=(const Optional<T>& t1, const Optional<T>& t2) {
    return !(t1 == t2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/14065).

```
int main()
{
    extra::Optional<int> x = Optional<int>of(new int(5));
    extra::Optional<int> y(x);   // This still compilers.

    // But your problems don't appear until here
    // at the end of scope.
}
```

### Design

Why do you force the construction of optional objects via the static methods?

```
    static Optional<T> of(const T &v);
    static Optional<T> of(T *v);
```

Why not allow people to just construct the objects in the normal way. It would seem more  natural to create objects of this type just like any other object!

### Move semantics

You may not want copy semantics (since you are basically implementing a smart pointer. But you could do with implementing move semantics on your object.

### Overall

I don't see the need.

If you want to return a pointer (but make sure it is managed). Then pass back a `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

If you are doing this as a learning exercise that's different. I'll give it a good going over once you have fixed the problems around the rule of three. But that is such a fundamental problem there is no point in reviewing this code further (Though in future version I would like a justification for the `static of()` methods and examples of why they are needed).

Comment: I have no idea why I did the `static of` methods. But I don't understand why such a class is not "needed". Java has an [Optional<T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class, as well as many other languages. The idea is that the class communicates more than a simple pointer (which could be null). What does `nullptr` mean anyways? For an `Optional`, it would simply mean that the value is not present.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear. Should this class be used to indicate an error in a function that should return some value? For example:

```
auto do_something() -> optional<int> { ... }

auto main() -> void {
    auto i = do_something();
    if (i.hasValue()) {
        // do_something() was ok.
    }
    else {
         // error case
    }
}
```

If this is the intention you may want to read https://github.com/ptal/std-expected-proposal for things to consider.

Also you may want to add a de-reference and boolean operators letting you do the following:

```
auto i = do_something();
if (i) {
     // success case
     int value = *i;
}
```

Doesn't make your code more correct but is less to type! I can provide my version of a similar class if it will help.